# Can you tie conductors together on lugs?

Tags: wiring

I'm replacing a bad light switch.  The current switch is wired as shown in the picture (two hot wires secured under a single lug).[image]

This looks unsafe and I'm concerned that one of the wires will come loose.  I'm putting in a pig tail, but wonder if the current wiring method is acceptable.

Comment: You should say which country you're in.

Comment: Hey @einpoklum, thanks for the suggestion.  I don't see location as being relevant to the question (it's either safe or not, which is not dependent on geographical location).  That said, I'm in the US.

Comment: Well, even for safety it may depend on the features of the grid where you live. But - your title said "Can you" which implies a question both about safety and about regulations/legality.

Comment: @einpoklum That's interesting.  What grid features would make this safe?

Comment: @einpoklum That's not safe in any country.

Comment: @J...: Maybe somewhere these wires carry low-voltage DC? ... hmm. Maybe not. Anyway, I was trying to generalize beyond this question, to make the point that it's usually appropriate to "geo-locate" the question.

Comment: @einpoklum DC?  Edison lost that fight LONG ago ;)  I think J...'s point, and my point, is that location plays no role here.

Comment: @tnknepp: Do you know for a fact that nowhere around the world can AC grid power be converted to DC and carried within apartment walls?

Comment: @einpoklum You need to accept that fact that your are being overly pedantic and fighting a fight that need not be fought.  Location here is not important; accept it.  If you believe there are places where "grid features" make this safe then it is on you to prove that.  If there are places that have these "grid features" then these are, by far, the exception to the rule.  We simply cannot address EVERY contingency here (but maybe...what if...) and, at some point, common sense has to prevail.

Answer (score 9):

### Definitely not allowed!

If you want to do that, then shop for certain *spec-grade* switches and receptacles ($3 instead of 60 cents), which have a feature some call "Screw-and-clamp".  This allows you to back-wire 2 wires under each screw, and you tighten the screw to clamp the wires.

Also note that since it's in a metal box, your switch does not require a ground wire.  It will pick up ground via the screw threads and head.   This trick doesn't work for receptacles unless the receptacles are labeled "self-grounding", which most of the "spec  grade" receptacles will be.

Comment: Thanks.  What if the ground wire is not connected to the metal box?  I assume I need to screw the ground wire to the box, correct?

Comment: If you have a metal box, the ground wire **must** be connected to it. If it's not, fix that.

Comment: @Ecnerwal The *incoming* ground wire must be connected to it.  (Show of hands, anyone who has ever found the incoming ground snipped at the cable entrance and the outgoing ground bonded to the box... 0_o)

Answer (score 5):

No, at least on the type pictured. You can only have one wire per screw. Your idea of a pig tail is exactly what you should do.

There do exist terminals that can support more than one wire, but this does not appear to be one.